# Any advice on my decisions surrounding Python GUI & database?

Tags: javascript, python, sql, mongodb, electron

So my next assignment for school involves creating a python GUI app with a database. I just have a couple basic questions that I am not yet 100% sure on the answers to.

1. I'm very good with `HTML` & `CSS`, however not so good at `Javascript` (I have about 8 weeks for this project however) - is creating an app with `ElectronJS` or even just in the web browser with `pywebview` a good idea or would I be best to stick with some of the older, uglier GUI frameworks such as `Tkinter` or `Kivy`?
2. Is there any major reason to learn how to use `NoSQL` databases over `SQL`? I already have a fairly decent understanding of SQL.
3. And finally, does using a GUI and a database (can the database even be inside the `.exe`?) pose any issues with packaging my whole project into a `.exe` or `.app` at the end or is this nothing to worry about?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- As gui with python goes i have mostly worked with pyqt5, its pretty good, it is a mature project,  you can even use it to comunicate with the database (sql databases) you can install the qt desigmer for a fast ui design, can apply css (or something really close to it) to your ui components and most important (at least for me) you will find a good amount of resources online on how to work with it and solve any issues that may arise.

Still if you want to go for a more electron like aproach and put your html and css skills to use, i would recomend Eel, it is fairly easy to use, i havent created anything too complex with it. Now these gui libraries that i mentioned , can be used with the module pyinstaller to create the executables that you need.

2-  If you already have some experience with sql, i recomend that you go with it for two reasons
First: sql database engine will fill most of your needs (if not all), go with nosql if you are dealing with huuuge amounts of data or you really want to learn nosql.
Second:I dont know if your project is going to comunicate with an external database or is embeded in the project, if it is embeded go with sqlite, if not, for sql i recomend postgres and for nosql use mongodb.

3- from my experience, sometimes it can get complicated trying to embed everything (database, other external files) within the executable but you can build the app to be in separated files, i recomend that you use for this like i wrote above pyinstaller, it is wel documented and both gui libraries work fine with it.
Hope this helps, everything i recomended to you is from personal expierience, there are plenty of database engines, python libraries you can use for the tasks needed to complete your project, check what suits you the best.

Good luck, sorry for my english.